# Need to run code only after backbone javascript fetch() call complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

In below code, I am trying to return `true` from `test2()`  to `test1()` in `if` block.
As In `test2()`,  variable `flag` is set to `true` in `fetch()` `success` block,
Now issue is that, due to backbone `fetch()` asynchronous call, `test2()` is returning `false` to `test1()` `if` block (due to this can not use if in `test1()`) and later, once the ajax call completed `test2()` `success` set `flag` to `true` but that is of no use, as it had already returned `false` to `test1()`.

So, please tell me, How to put any delay/ or run if block in `test2()`  only when `flag` value is set in fetch `success` block
I have tried with `_.delay()`, `delay()` but not work for me.
Please help on this issue, as I had put a lot of days but unable to figure out fix for this.

```
test1 :function()
{
    var x = true;
    if(x && this.test2())// call to test2
     {
         // run the code here
     }
},

test2: function()
{ 
    var flag = false;// default value
    noteCaseTeam = App.data.createBean('Module',{id:123});//Return the object of Team  
    noteCaseTeam.fetch(
    {
        success:function() // working fine
        {
            flag =true;//setting flag to true
            case_number_team  = noteCaseTeam.get('name');
        }
    }); // end of fetch function  
    if (flag) //Control is not reaching here due to "flag" default value
    {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
},// end of test2
```

Thanks !!

Comment: Don't put things like "urgent" in the title of your quesiton. It's irrelevant, and gets in the way of people seeing your question. Seprately: When asking for help, take the time to format your code readably. You can use any bracing style or indentation you like in your own code, but when asking others to read and help you with it, you should use something *vaguely* common.

Answer (score 0):

You can't return `Boolean` with async call.

You better use `sync` callback, to run your `test1`:

```
this.listenTo(CaseTeam, 'sync', test1);
```

`CaseTeam` should be available inside your code.

If you provide reduced test case, i will improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to learn how JQuery promises work: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wrangle-async-tasks-with-jquery-promises--net-24135

```js
test1 :function()
{
    var x = true;

    // Call test2() and wait it
    this.test2().done(function (response) {
        if (x) {
            // run the code here
        }
    });
},

test2: function()
{ 
    var noteCaseTeam = App.data.createBean('Module',{id:123});//Return the object of Team  
    return noteCaseTeam.fetch().done(
        function(response) {
            case_number_team  = noteCaseTeam.get('name');
        }
    );
},
```